# Setting default properties for toolbox items?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I don't want the button I add to have dotted borders when clicked, so I found out that I can disable that by turning off the focus cues. I don't want to have to change settings like this for each individual button I add. Is there any way to set property defaults in Visual Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hiding dashed outline around trackbar control when selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484270/hiding-dashed-outline-around-trackbar-control-when-selected)

Comment: @DaveShaw: it is related, but not duplicated...

Comment: @MatthiasKoch - good point, posted an answer with how to implement.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to set/change/remove focus style on a Button in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148729/how-to-set-change-remove-focus-style-on-a-button-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create a new Control based on `Button` and use it throughout your application.

```
public class MyButton : System.Windows.Forms.Button
{
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although it is a solution, it is not an answer to the question. This would also force him to replace all present buttons with the new MyButton class.

Comment: I don't think it's possible any other way. A quick peek with ILSpy at the code inside ShowFocusCues doesn't render anything that can be set.